# Using ADC of PIC18F4520 to convert full-wave rectified analog signal to digital

Tags: pic, adc

I am building a AC voltage and current (50 Hz) data logger and I have built and tested the measuring circuit and it works fine. I used an ideal full-wave rectifier to reflect the negative voltages to positive and my challenge now is converting the rectified signal to digital using the built-in modules of the PIC18F4520 (Microchip claims that the ADC this MCU can do  100K samples per second) so that I save the measured signal to the SD card. I am aware of the Nyquist theorem. What are the steps I should follow?

Comment: Write some code to sample and save?

Answer (score 0):

> What are the steps I should follow?

a few:

1) read and understand the datasheet;

2) design an AFE to suit your mcu;

3) write the code to sample the rectified ac;

4) done.